# Is it possible to hide nav menu items only when they are page titles (on specific templates) but not on the dashboard?

Tags: custom-post-types, php

I want to hide the page titles that use a custom page template. So I've written code that filters out the page title when the custom page template is enabled. However, that resulted in the nav menu items being filtered too. So I added more code to remove the filter if it is a menu item and add it back after. But now, the titles are being filtered in the Dashboard as shown in the picture. How do I prevent this?

The code that I added is as follows:

```
function suppressed_title($title,$id) {
if(get_page_template_slug()=='custom-template.php' && get_post_type($id)=='page') {
  $title='';
}
return $title; }
add_filter('the_title', 'suppressed_title',10,2);

function remove_title_filter($nav_menu, $args) { 
  remove_filter('the_title', 'suppressed_title',10,2);
  return $nav_menu;
}
add_filter('pre_wp_nav_menu', 'remove_title_filter',10,2);

function add_title_filter($items, $args) {
  //add the filter after filtering out the menu items
  add_filter('the_title', 'suppressed_title',10,2);
  return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_title_filter',10,2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`is_admin()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/) to check if the request is done being inside /wp-admin.

```
function suppressed_title($title, $id) {
    if (is_admin()) {
        return $title;
    }
    if (get_page_template_slug() === 'custom-template.php' && get_post_type($id) === 'page') {
        $title = '';
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'suppressed_title', 10, 2);
```

I changed your code to use triple equals `===` over `==` as this is usually considered best practice. (See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/80649) for more info.)

---

> I want to hide the page titles that use a custom page template

Technically, you're not hiding the title right now, but displaying an empty title. This might have effects on the styling anyway. In my opinion a cleaner solution would be not to display the title at all at these pages. But this is highly dependent on which theme you are using.

Comment: The code worked. Thank you so much! I'm new at this so your help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: If I may suggest, please have a look at [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/). If you keep this code style, most PHP developers around the world will easily be able to read your code. You can see that I changed your code to it, e.g. 4 spaces for indentation, spaces between relevant things, etc.

Comment: Sure thing. Thank you again.